# how to capture cell address as a variable and use in VB code?

Tags: variables, excel, cell, vba

Need a code snippet; if some kind guru could help, please.  I need to express the following cursor movement sequence in XL VBA.

After entering a formula in cell A1 (Col-A is otherwise empty), I need to copy the formula to all cells in the range A1:AN, where N is the last row of the table.

I recorded a macro to do the following (code below):

1) enter the formula (in Cell A1)

2) copy the formula

3) go Right to B1

4) go to the last populated cell in Col-B [using Ctrl+Down] (easiest way to find the last row)

5) go Left to Col-A

6) select all cells from current to A1

7) paste the formula to the selection

The part I need help with is a way to capture the cell address in step 5 as a variable so that I can use this macro on a series of files having a variable number of rows.

Here is the recorded macro.  In this example, the last row in the table is 7952.

```
Sub test()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],3)"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-7951, 0).Range("A1:A7951").Select
    ActiveCell.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Todd and user2063626,

I decided on a simpler approach.  I only needed to obtain the last row in order to set my selection area; the number of the last row is not used in the actual values to be written.  The files to be manipulated are flat ascii exports; the column layout is constant, only the number of rows is variable.

After writing the formula to A1, I move down column B and test for a value one cell at a time; if TRUE, copy the formula to the left adjacent cell; if FALSE, end process.

```
Sub FillClientCodes()

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],3)"
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
CheckCell:
    ActiveCell.Activate
    If ActiveCell.Value <> 0 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        GoTo CheckCell
    Else: GoTo EndOfData
    End If
EndOfData:

End Sub
```

It's not elegant - it runs slower than a single select and paste - but it works, and it will work on all the files I need to process.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your end cell is always going to be the same, meaning you may want to "un" hard code the rows, but you could try this.

```
Sub test()
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(7951, 1)) = "=LEFT(RC[1],3)"
End Sub
```

If you are always going to put equations in column A based on the number of rows used in column B you could try this.

```
Sub test()
    ' dimension the variable type
    Dim lastRow As Long
    ' select cell "B1"
    Cells(1, 2).Select
    ' jump to the last consecutive row in column B
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ' collect the row number into a variable
    lastRow = ActiveCell.Row
    ' paste the equation into the variable length range
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)) = "=LEFT(RC[1],3)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly copy the below code to the worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


    If Target.Address = "$A$1" And Target.Count = 1 And Target.HasFormula Then

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

        '        Target.Copy
        '        rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas

        'OR
        '  rng.Formula = Target.Formula

       ' OR

        rng.FormulaR1C1 = Target.FormulaR1C1

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```